# Dynamic authorisation system in page level

Tags: java, authorization, seam, access-control

I wanted to design a authorisation system for a web application. The system should provide the super user the privilege to assign the permissions to the users that was registered dynamically. i.e super user can give a certain user the permission to view a certain page while giving another user the permission to view and edit. Can some one guide me on a implementation or a framework to achieve this.  Iam using SEAM but it don't have a dynamic authorisation system as such.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Seam, the security components provided with the framework should allow you to satisfy your requirements.

I suggest to start reading the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.Final/reference/en-US/html/security.html) about those features. In addition to credential and permission management you also have a rule (Drools) based permission resolver (useful, for instance, to create one superuser with all permissions automatically assigned).